# p:schedule size is too small

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, schedule, aspect-ratio

I'm using a `<p:schedule>`.
Here is my code:

```
<h:panelGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%" columnClasses="value">
    <p:schedule  resizable="false"
                 initialDate="#{visitBean.startingTime}"
                 aspectRatio="0.01"
                 minTime="10am"
                 maxTime="5pm"
                 firstHour="9"
                 id="schedule"
                 view="agendaDay"
                 slotMinutes="90"
                 allDaySlot="false"
                 value="#{visitBean.eventModel}"
                 widgetVar="myschedule"
                 timeZone="GMT+5">

        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                listener="#{visitBean.onDateSelect}"
                update="schedule,:Form:vis_tm"/>
        <p:ajax event="eventSelect"
                listener="#{visitBean.onEventSelect}"
                update="schedule"/>
        <p:ajax event="eventMove"
                listener="#{visitBean.onEventMove}"
                update="messages,:Form:vis_tm"/>

        <!--oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" -->
        <!--update="eventDetails" -->
    </p:schedule>
```

I don't know whats wrong. I try to set the `aspectRatio` as small as possible but still the size of my schedule stays small. How can i increase the size of my schedule?

Comment: Your `p:schedule` has to look like the original one in the PF showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml If not, there's some extra css interfering on it, so have a look at the loaded classes in your browser inspector and see what's going on.

Comment: Its size is too small, its probably because of my slotMinutes and minTime and maxTime, but i need to know how i can increase the height of my slots without changing the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your slotMinutes atttribute value 90 to any other value such as 30   then automatically the size is increased.